# scan the 2nd digit of an integer

Tags: c, scanf

This program is taking two numbers (two digits each) as input.  It then takes the second digit of the first entry and pairs it with the first character of the second entry.

example input:

8**9** **4**3

output:

94

(9 is the 2nd digit of the first number and 4 is the 1st digit of the 2nd number). I know how to scan the first number of an integer but i cant seem to figure out how to scan the 2nd digit.

**Edit:** this is where I am stuck:

```
int a,b;

scanf("%d %1d",&a,&b);
printf("%d %d",a,b);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Input as two strings: `scanf("%s%s", s1, s2)` and then examine the strings (including their length).

Comment: @Osiris i've edited my post

Comment: Can these be input? 1, 100, 01, 09, 0, 9000

Comment: @Yunnosch the idea of the program is just to take the last digit of the first number and the first non 0 digits of the last number.

Comment: `printf("%d%d\n", a%10, b>=10 ? b/10 : b);`

Comment: Restricting the input with `%1d` can leave some input in the buffer (as well as the newline) which can mess up a future input. Better to input the numbers as given, and then use a combination of division and modulus operators on them. Or as mentioned, work with strings.

Comment: Assuming that the input is two positive integers and each contains 2 digits, you can `scanf("%1d%1d %1d%1d", &num1_digit1, &num1_digit0, &num2_digit1, &num2_digit0);` and then just `printf("%d%d\n", num1_digit0, num2_digit1);`

Answer (score 0):

> program is taking two numbers (two digits each) as input
>   scan the 2nd digit of an integer

Scanning in 1 digit is not a robust way to meet the end goal.  Simply scan in the 2 `int`s, test if `< 100` and then use `/10` and `%10` to extract digits.

This approach is far easier to detect and handle errant input.

```
int a,b;

if (scanf("%d %d",&a,&b) != 2) puts("Bad input");
else if (a < 10 || a >= 99 || b < 10 || b > 99) puts("Input out of range");
else {
  printf("%d %d --> ",a,b);
  printf("%d%d\n",a%10,b/10);
}
```

---

Should code want to handle leading zeros, code could read in the *line* with `fgets()` and then parse in various ways.  Sticking with `scanf()`, code can use `"%n"` to note the scan offset.

```
int n1,n2,n3,n4=0;
if (scanf(" %n%d%n %n%d%n",&n1,&a,&n2, &n3,&b,&n4) != 2) puts("Bad input");
else if (n2-n1 != 2 || a < 0 || n4-n3 != 2 || b < 0) puts("Input out of range");
else {
 /* as above */
}
```

Note: This still does not flag input like `"+3 -0"` as bad.

Answer (score 0):

If you're confident that you'll only have two pairs of digits to deal with, then consider using the `*` modifier to suppress assignment:

```
if (scanf("%*1d%1d %1d%*1d", &a, &b) != 2)
    …oops…
else
    printf("%d%d\n", a, b);
```

The space in the input format is optional since `%1d` will skip it anyway.  You can't tell whether the last `%*1d` failed to match.

If the input data format is not reliable, use `fgets()` to read a line and then `sscanf()` to parse it; you can report errors much better and retry with different formats if appropriate.  Also, using string/character input is another option.